# The Odi Project - "sqlite3 is not part of the bundle"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, web-development-server

First and foremost, excuse my lack of knowledge in Ruby and me most likely misusing certain terms throughout this post; I'm extremely new to this and I'm barely getting the hang of everything.

OS: Mac os X El Capitan

Anyways, I'm following "The Odin Project" which is an introduction to web development program and I've been following every step carefully up until the point where it says to execute the following command in terminal

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

and I get a bunch of errors

```
Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ floating-falls-25848... up, run.9253 (Free)
rails aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:185:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `<class:MySQLDatabaseTasks>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:3:in `<module:Tasks>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:74:in `<module:DatabaseTasks>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:35:in `<module:Tasks>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:186:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `<class:MySQLDatabaseTasks>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:3:in `<module:Tasks>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:74:in `<module:DatabaseTasks>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:35:in `<module:Tasks>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

This is what my Gemfile file looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '2.3.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

(Just a portion of the code to show where 'sqlite3' is)

EDIT: This is what my database.ysml file looks like:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: Post your `config/database.yml`. I believe you'll find that it specifies `sqlite3` as your production database adapter.

Comment: @jvillian This is what it says:

`default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000


development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3


production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3}`

Comment: Please add to your question, it's too hard to read as a comment (with correct formatting). As suspected, you're not specifying postgresql as your database adapter, thus your error.\

Comment: @jvillian Edited the main post. Could you explain what you mean when you said "by not specifying my postgresql?"

Answer (score 1):

You have your database and adapter set up incorrectly in `config/database.yml`.

Here:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
```

You are specifying that your default database adapter is sqlite3. Then, in production, you do:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

See how you never specify an `adapter:` value? That means you're using the one you set in `default`, which is `sqlite3`.

Also, you're specifying that the database to use in production is `db/production.sqlite3`, which is, naturally, incorrect.

Your production config should look something more like:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter:  postgresql
  database: contacts_production
  username: contacts
  password: <%= ENV['CONTACTS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

See how it says, `adapter: postgresql`? That will override your default. So, in production (on Heroku), you are configured to use `postgresql` instead of `sqlite3`.

Of course, you need your own `database:`, `username:`, and `password:` (I just pulled something from one of my projects). This may not be all exactly correct, so you'll have to fuss with it a bit.

Also, if you have the option, you should use postgresql for all of your environments. The databases have subtle (and not so subtle) differences and you're just setting yourself up for heartache by using different databases in different environments.

Comment: Did you end up sorting this out?